# MessageDialog freezes when created from Slot qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, signals-slots

I am trying to show message dialog from worker thread. Using slots and signals is standard way of communicating with/calling QML objects, but when dialog appears it's button is unclickable/not responding.

main.cpp

```
tester* test = new tester;
QtConcurrent::run(test,tester::testFunction);
```

tester.cpp

```
#include "tester.h"
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>

tester::tester(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {
    QObject::connect(this,SIGNAL(show()),this,SLOT(showSlot()));
}
void tester::testFunction() {
    emit show();
}
void tester::showSlot(){
    QQmlEngine engine;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/BlockingDialog.qml")));
    QObject *object = component.create();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(object, "open");
}
```

tester.h

```
#include <QObject>

class tester : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit tester(QObject *parent = 0);
    void testFunction();
signals:
    void show();
public slots:
    void showSlot();
};
```

BlockingDialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

MessageDialog {
    id:dialog    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the QML engine on the stack in `showSlot()`, so it will be destroyed when the function finishes. The typical approach to loading QML files is to create the QML engine on the stack in `main()`.